# Missing Source Control Plugin in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

After a computer crash I had to reinstall Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.
But after the installation the Source Control Plugin option (Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection) is not showing any option available.
Before reinstall I use the TFS normally.

I've tried several things:

1. Uninstall make a clean installation (a few times, even deleted the directories and cleaned the registry entries before reinstall).
2. I've downloaded Visual Studio Team Explorer and install it independently.

Please help

Comment: Have you already connected to the TFS with the freshly installed VS?

Comment: The TFS is up and running. I ping it ok and can access it via sharepoint.

But there is not menu item in VS2010 to connect it. The Team Explorer window is not available even in the view menu and no option to configure in the Source Safe providers list.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, fixed it by downloading the team explorer via this link

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329

Not quite sure how that wasn't installed with the Ultimate Media either.

This is an .iso image and I use Virtual Clone Drive to mount the image.

http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Visual Studio Help > About and ensure that the component "Team Explorer" is present.